# Always start google chrome in full screen

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know a way to make chrome always start in full screen? (normally it's when you press the button to the top right, you'd find a "full screen button" in the zoom option).

Not <kbd>f11</kbd> full screen; it's different! try it.

Comment: I think the exact procedure may depend on your window manager.

Comment: I dont use chrome so I wont answer but maybe Darren Hall's answer will work, http://superuser.com/questions/88867/is-there-a-way-to-make-google-chrome-running-under-ubuntu-open-fullscreen-by-d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the best option is to use the kiosk mode, even if it's not really the F11 Fullscreen mode that you expected.

Open the **.desktop file** of Chrome:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

You need to add the `--kiosk` option in three places:

```
[Desktop Entry]
[...]
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --kiosk %U
[...]
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
[...]
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --kiosk
[...]
[NewIncognito Shortcut Group]
[...]
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --kiosk --incognito
```

Hitting F11 does not work since it's not a true Fullscreen mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to quit.

Comment: ummm okay thank you. What is the difference between a normal full screen mode and this kiosk mode?

Comment: Its initial purpose was to be used in public areas. I did some tests and one limitation is the lack of tabs.

Comment: lack of tabs!!!!! oh no I can't live with that! Chrome is all about tabs you know XD

Comment: I can't find a better solution unfortunately and most of the chrome command line options are not documented. But as they are the same for Ubuntu and Windows I guess that the kiosk mode is the best we can do. You could run always maximized though if it's acceptable for you, there are some third-party programs that provide this feature

Comment: mmm I think I'll search again. ...are you sure you can't open tabs in the kiosk mode? try Ctrl+T

Comment: Well you can open tabs but you can't see them. But if navigating with keyboard shortcuts is not a problem for you, then Ctrl+PgUp or Ctrl+PgDown will help you to switch between opened tabs.